# CSS: How to Solve this "Site-Is-Too-Big" Challenge?

Tags: css, resolution, horizontal-scrolling

I suspect my question may be too general, but I hope someone with expertly knowledge of CSS could help me work out a solution.

My site looks acceptable (to me) in high-resolution monitors (1920X1080) – but on smaller-resolution screens the left site doesn't fit - and even though the horizontal scrolling appears eventually of you make the window smaller, but it appears "too late" and doesn't include anything left of the main content panel.

That's the particularly I'm particularly concerned about. There are other resolution-related problems, too.

Here's the site:

http://www.cybart.com/bscg/

I would appreciate it if you could take a look – and would be grateful for suggestions / recommendations / advice from CSS masters!

Comment: The problem is `margin-left: -600px;` on `#access`.  The solution I'm not sure of.

Comment: Thank you Jawad. Could you please try again? My hosting company is being rather liberal about server downtime lately. Usually the site will load if you try again in a minute or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I understand your problem:

If someone goes to your website on a smaller screen, maybe 1024x768 or something, there's no scroll bar's appearing.

You need to set up a minimum width / height for a div container for the page content.  Then if the browser is narrower than that you'll get the scroll bar.

I suggest instead that you make one div tag that won't be wider than say, 950 and put a nice background behind it instead.  No one wants to scroll left or right in the browser.

Use width and height css tags on a div containing the page content.

Comment: Thank you David. What you're saying makes perfect sense, but I am actually limited by what my client wants. They want a full-screen background for any screen resolution. I would be grateful for any other suggestions from you.

Comment: You can still have a full screen background.  For example, see http://www.sendtoperson.com.  Try making the window wider and narrower.  The background sizes to fit the screen but if you make it too narrow, you see the horizontal scroll bar.  You can also see another example of this at http://www.socialnetwork.com.  Both have the content inside a container div, that is sitting on a background that scales to fit the window, but have a minimum width.

Comment: Combine my answer with Jason Gennaro's and you have a good solution.  Use the margin auto stuff to put your main content in the center, and still have a background that fills the whole browser window.  Then the min-width css tag will give you the horizontal scroll bar if the user makes the browser too small.

Answer (score 1):

I have a lower resolution screen... and I see the issue.

You might consider shrinking the size of the main content section and then shifting over the nav.

Or -- better -- auto center your main section using `margin:0 auto;` and then position the left nav accordingly.

Comment: Thank you Jason. Do you mean that auto-centering it with margin:0 auto; will make the scrollbar appear when it's necessary?

Comment: Could you please try to make the width of the window smaller until it corresponds to the width of the main content panel? You will see that the scrollbar appears eventually, but for some reason it doesn't include anything to the left of the main content panel. Could you diagnose that issue?

Comment: Not necessarily.  But if you content is auto centred and a decent width (say less than 1024px), then it should all appear on most screens.

Comment: Thanks. Heres what's weird: I set up the margin: 0 auto; and instead of doing what it would normally do, it made the content appear all the way to the left of the screen.

Comment: The `margin-left: -600px;` on the  `<div id="access">` is causing the nav to be positioned to far left.  Adjust that and the middle piece.

Comment: Actually, I take it back. I removed the margin-left:-600; and set margin for mane panel to 0 auto – and yet it still appears all the way on the left. But it's okay, I suppose I can figure out what makes it do that.

Answer (score 0):

The scrolling bars issue has to do with page overflow. You might be using overflow:hidden and when the page doesn't fit the browser doesn't show the scrollbars.

Comment: No, there's no overflow: hidden assigned to the body, html or any div that is 100% wide.